# Nginx: multiple domains not working

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to have multiple sites on the same server. I have a DigitalOcean VPS with Debian and Nginx. Whatever I go to site1.com, site2.com or site3.com, the site shows the site1.com content. Also, when I type www.site.com, www.site2.com or www.site3.com Chrome shows "This webpage is not available"

On .../sites-available/ and .../sites-enabled/ I have the site1.com, site2.com and site3.com files with the following content. This is from site1.com:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name site1.com  www.site1.com;
access_log /opt/www/site1.com/access.log;

root /opt/www/site1.com; }
```

This is from site2.com:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name site2.com  www.site2.com;
access_log /opt/www/site2.com/access.log;

root /opt/www/site2.com; }
```

And from site3.com:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name site3.com  www.site3.com;
access_log /opt/www/site3.com/access.log;

root /opt/www/site3.com; }
```

What am I doing wrong? As you may predict, yes, this is my first time setting up a Nginx server.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you restart nginx? Did you check your DNS? Those aren't your real domain names...

Comment: Yes, I restarted Nginx and checked my DNS but still doesn't work. I used those names for example :)

Comment: do all the 3 sites DNS name point to the IP addresses configured on DO VPS ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Nginx which documents to serve from the root domain directories if the directory is requested by the client.

Try adding:

```
    index index.html index.htm;
```

below the root declaration. This will tell nginx what file types to serve from the directory

*You have to reload/restart nginx after any configuration changes.*

For reference:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html

Comment: I added that line below the root declaration and now it works! Thank you very much! Problem solved.

Comment: Dont forget to accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: `You have to restart nginx after any configuration changes.`. Just to clear things out - you may reload nginx as well.

Comment: @Glueon Yes thanks Glueon I have updated the answer with clarification.